# how to add condition in the with clause of yii active record?

Tags: php, yii

i have a with clause in my criteria like this

```
$criteria2->with = array('subcat','adimages');
```

but i actually need to have this subcat to be unique, but if i will add a condition like this

```
$criteria2 = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria2->select = '"t".USERID, "t".ADID ,"t".ADTYPE, "t".ADTITLE, "t".ADDESC, "t".PAGEVIEW, "t".DISPPUBLISHDATE,"t".SUBCATID';
$criteria2->addCondition("USERID IN (".implode(',',$uniqueuser).")");
$criteria2->addCondition("ADID IN (".implode(',',$uniquead).")");
//  $criteria2->addCondition("SUBCATID IN(".implode(',',$uniquesubcat).")");
//  $criteria2->compare("\"t\".SUBCATID", $this->SUBCATID);
$criteria2->addCondition('DISPPUBLISHDATE >= CURRENT_DATE - 3 AND STATUS = 1
        AND EXPIRYDATE >= CURRENT_DATE AND USERID IS NOT NULL');
$criteria2->addCondition('EXISTS  (select 1 FROM {{ADIMAGES}} WHERE {{ADIMAGES}}.ADID = "t".ADID)');
$criteria2->order = '"t".PAGEVIEW DESC,"t".PUBLISHDATE DESC';
$criteria2->limit = 4;
$criteria2->addCondition("\"subcat\".SUBCATID IN(".implode(',',$uniquesubcat).")");     
$criteria2->with = array('subcat','adimages');
$result2 = $this->findAll($criteria2);
return $result2;
```

am getting an error of ambigious column defined...
how do i set that subcat relation to be inside the unique

```
$uniquesubcat arrray ?
```

Comment: Another usefull question closed

Answer (score 4):

Try set table alias like this

```
$criteria2 = new CDbCriteria();
// SELECT
$criteria2->select = 't.USERID, t.ADID, t.ADTYPE, t.ADTITLE, t.ADDESC, t.PAGEVIEW, t.DISPPUBLISHDATE, subcat.SUBCATID';
// JOIN
$criteria2->with = array('subcat','adimages');
// WHERE
$criteria2->compare('t.STATUS', 1);
$criteria2->addCondition('t.DISPPUBLISHDATE >= CURRENT_DATE - 3');
$criteria2->addCondition('t.EXPIRYDATE >= CURRENT_DATE');
$criteria2->addCondition('t.USERID IS NOT NULL');
$criteria2->addCondition('EXISTS  (select 1 FROM {{ADIMAGES}} as ADIMAGES WHERE ADIMAGES.ADID = t.ADID)');

$criteria2->addInCondition('t.USERID', $uniqueuser);
$criteria2->addInCondition('t.ADID', $uniquead);
$criteria2->addInCondition('subcat.SUBCATID', $uniquesubcat);     
// ORDER
$criteria2->order = 't.PAGEVIEW DESC, t.PUBLISHDATE DESC';
// LIMIT
$criteria2->limit = 4;

$result2 = $this->findAll($criteria2);
return $result2;
```

Comment: why you used compare ? ,

Comment: It's example - you use same named column in condition, or tables has same named columns, you need specify which table SUBCATID you use

Comment: it didn't helped, am getting same result UID=201087; AID=626582; SID=40; PVIEW=7;
UID=201087; AID=626581; SID=113; PVIEW=7;
UID=201140; AID=626551; SID=37; PVIEW=7;
UID=201139; AID=626550; SID=113; PVIEW=7;

Comment: see the SID ? , there is still duplicate

Comment: Please show complete criteria compilation from $criteria = new CDBCriteria ans so on

Comment: Do not set " for "t".USERID - t.USERID is good

Comment: hmm...missing right parenthesis, i wonder where is the missing one..hard to guess in the error output where the whole sql statement result is displayed

Comment: @sasori, do you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I see here you're trying to build a query criteria for a CActiveRecord, but I think you should keep in mind that CDbCriteria->with is used for ***Eager Loading***, meaning that you will get a CActiveRecord object including the related CActiveRecord(s) specified by relation name in CDbCriteria->with.

So, if you're looking for one subcat and you loaded all the subcats eagerly, you should filter it.

1. You could iterate on $models->subcat if it is an array.
2. You could use the join condition of CDbCriteria in order to replace the with condition.

I prefer the 2nd alternative.

```
$criteria2->join = "LEFT JOIN subcat s ON (s.SUBCATID = t.SUBCATID)"
```

So, you could change this:

```
$criteria2->addInCondition('subcat.SUBCATID', $uniquesubcat);
```

for

```
$criteria2->addInCondition('s.SUBCATID', $uniquesubcat);
```

In conclusion, you can use the [join property of CDbCriteria](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#join-detail) to give `subcat` an alias and disambiguate your query.